# Input Error: There is no file extension

Tags: batch-file

If this is a rookie mistake I apologize for wasting your time.

As part of a larger batch file to create a directory with today's date, copy and paste files to be backed up, change permissions and delete files older then X days I've run into a problem.  Here's where it happens:

```
echo var D = new Date() > tmp.js
echo D = (D.getFullYear()*100+D.getMonth()+1)*100+D.getDate() >> tmp.js
echo WScript.Echo( 'set YYYYMMDD='+D ) >> tmp.js
echo @echo off > tmp.bat
cscript //nologo tmp.js >> tmp.bat
call tmp.bat
```

The command prompt spits back this error:

```
Input Error: There is no file extension in "C:\Users\name\Desktop\Error:".
```

So obviously the rest of the batch file fails but the weird thing is this works on one machine on the network but not the other.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: there is one more line to that code that is returning the error, my mistake.
After I call tmp.bat:

```
mkdir "\\network\file\%YYYYMMDD%"
```

Comment: DosTips not good enuff for ya, eh? :D

Comment: That's funny, you monitoring both then?  I just figured more eyes would mean a faster answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

running `cscript` on `tmp.js` led to an error begin put into `tmp.bat`

`call tmp.bat` then returned the weird input error because of the error message inside of `tmp.bat`.

`tmp.bat` looked like this when editing

```
Cscript Error: Can't find script engine "JScript" for script "C:\Users\name\Desktop\tmp.js".
```

That's why calling tmp.bat returned this error message:

```
Input Error: There is no file extension in "C:\Users\name\Desktop\error:".
```

The problem ended up being with jscript.dll. It needed to be (re)registered.

```
regsvr32 %systemroot%\system32\jscript.dll
```

^Fixed my problem.  Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This code, as is, will not generate the indicated error

BUT, if the path to the batch file contains spaces, and the code is something like

```
cscript //nologo %~dp0\tmp.js
```

you will get the indicated error as the argument to cscript is incorrectly parsed because the space in the path to the js file. If this is the case (or something similar), quotes in the filename should solve it

```
cscript //nologo "%~dp0\tmp.js"
```

Also, the temporary batch file is not needed. Output from cscript can be directly read with the help of `for` command

```
set "tmpJS=%~dp0\tmp.js"
>"%tmpJS%" echo with(new Date()){WScript.StdOut.WriteLine(getFullYear()*10000+(getMonth()+1)*100+getDate())};
for /f %%D in ('cscript //nologo //B "%tmpJS%"') do set "YYYYMMDD=%%D"
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip with the for command.  I'll come back to that when I get this solved.  I'm not using full path names because i'm deleting the temporary files at the end of the batch file.  There is, however, a space in the computer name (I didn't name it).  So technically the path would be something like this:  "C:\Users\name name\Desktop\", do you think that is causing the error?  I edited my OP, there is one additional line that could possibly be causing the error.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: @JoeNoName, no, not indicating a full path to the file excludes the problem with spaces. Is it possible that the machine in where you are having problems has some kind of "alias" for cscript?. Try to replace call to cscript with `c:\windows\system32\cscript.exe` to exclude this option.

Comment: I tried calling the full cscript.exe path file name.  No dice.  Was really hoping you were right.  Still don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Wow - that is a very convoluted way to get the current date in a variable.

This is not a direct answer to your question, but I think I can make your life much easier :-)

There really is no need for a temporary batch file. FOR /F could process the output of your temporary JS script directly.

But I have an even easier solution - [GetTimeStamp.bat](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4847&p=27422#p27422) is a hybrid JScript/batch utility that can do nearly any date and time computation on a Windows machine.

The utility is pure script that will run on any modern Windows machine from XP forward - no 3rd party executable required.

Assuming getTimestamp.bat is in your current directory, or better yet, somewhere within your PATH, then the following simple call will define a `YYYYMMDD` variable containing today's date in YYYYMMDD format:

```
call getTimeStamp -f {yyyy}{mm}{dd} -r YYYYMMDD
```

There are a great many options for specifying the base date and time, many options for adding positive or negative offsets to the date and time, many options for formatting the result, and an option to capture the result in a variable. Both input and output can be directly expressed as local time, UTC, or any time zone of your choosing. Full documentation is embedded within the script.

Comment: plugging our own work, are we?  I'm j/k, that script is very very cool.  Thank you so much for turning me on to it.